# Magento export orders to 3PL soap api issue

Tags: api, magento, soap

I have been reimplementing this script for a client after upgrade and I'm stuck (perhaps the brain is fried). Most of it is none of your concern. The part I'm having an issue with is here:

```
try

         {

            $customer_exists = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order.info', $ShippedOrderId);
         }

         catch (exception $e)

         {

            echo 'Exception: ' . $e . "<br/>";

         }
```

It's throwing the following exception:

"Exception: SoapFault exception: [100] Requested order not exists. in /home/ab71714/public_html/exporter/importer-sftp.php:140 Stack trace: #0 /home/ab71714/public_html/exporter/importer-sftp.php(140): SoapClient->__call('call', Array) #1 /home/ab71714/public_html/exporter/importer-sftp.php(140): SoapClient->call('9cafc83722b06f2...', 'sales_order.inf...', '100015822') #2 {main}"

The whole thing is following.
Any help with be enormously appreciated!

```
     <?php 

   ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); 

   ini_set('display_errors', 1); 


var_dump(extension_loaded('ssh2'));
   // URL to Magento SOAP API

   $client = new SoapClient('http://animalnecessity.com/api/soap?wsdl'); 

   $apiuser = ''; 

   $apikey = ''; 



   // FTP info

   $ftp_server = 'ftp.3plworldwide.com';

   $ftp_user_name = '';

   $ftp_user_pass = '';



   // Address to mail report to

   $mail_to = '';



   $mail_content = "Checking for 3PL shipping import files on " . date('m/d/Y') . "\n\n";



   /*** Begin FTP ***/



   // Set up SFTP connection

   $conn_id = ssh2_connect($ftp_server, 22);

   $login_result = ssh2_auth_password($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

   $sftp = ssh2_sftp($conn_id);



   // Check connection results

   if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 

       $mail_content .= "SFTP connection has failed.\n";

       $mail_content .= "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server under user '$ftp_user_name', password '$ftp_user_pass'.\n\n"; 

   } else {

       $mail_content .= "Successfully connected to $ftp_server with an SFTP secure connection, under user '$ftp_user_name', password '$ftp_user_pass'.\n\n"; 

   }



   // Download the files in the SHIPMENTS folder

   $download = true;

   $dirHandle = opendir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/SHIPMENTS/");

   if ($dirHandle)

   {

      $filelist = '';

      $downarray = array();

      while (false !== ($file = readdir($dirHandle)))

      {

         if (strpos($file, 'OCU_SHP_') !== false)

         {

            // Choose only shipment files up to 7 days back

            $datetag = substr($file, 8, 6);

            $year = substr($datetag, 0, 2);

            $month = substr($datetag, 2, 2);

            $day = substr($datetag, 4, 2);

            if (!is_numeric($year)) { continue; }

            $datestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year);

            if ($datestamp > strtotime('-7 days'))

            {

               $fileName = 'SHIPMENTS/' . $file;

               // Remote stream

               if (!$remoteStream = @fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/$fileName", 'r'))

               {

                  $mail_content .= "Unable to open remote file: $fileName\n";

                  $download = false;

               } 

               // Local stream

               if (!$localStream = @fopen("./$fileName", 'w'))

               {

                  $mail_content .= "Unable to open local file for writing: ./$fileName\n";

                  $download = false;

               }

               // Write from our remote stream to our local stream

               $read = 0;

               $fileSize = filesize("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/$fileName");

               while ($read < $fileSize && ($buffer = fread($remoteStream, $fileSize - $read)))

               {

                  // Increase our bytes read

                  $read += strlen($buffer);

                  // Write to our local file

                  if (fwrite($localStream, $buffer) === FALSE)

                  {

                      $mail_content .= "Unable to write to local file: /localdir/$fileName\n";

                      $download = false;

                  }

               }

               // Close our streams

               fclose($localStream);

               fclose($remoteStream);

               // Update file lists for mail content and imports

               $filelist .= $file . "\n";

               array_push($downarray, './SHIPMENTS/' . $file);

            }

         } 

      }

   }



   // check download status

   if (!$download) { 

       $mail_content .= "Some file download(s) failed.\n\n";

   }

   else

   {

      $mail_content .= "Successfully downloaded all of the following files from $ftp_server:\n\n";

      $mail_content .= $filelist . "\n";

   }



   /*** End FTP ***/



   /*** Begin Import ***/



   // Read data from downloaded files into array

   $lines = array();

   foreach ($downarray as $file)

   {

      $linesnew = file($file);

      $lines = array_merge($lines, $linesnew);

   }

   var_dump($lines);

   // Connect to Magento Web Services API

   $sess_id = $client->login($apiuser, $apikey); 


   $mail_content .= "Importing the following shipments:\n\n===\n\n";

   $dupecount = 0;

   $importcount = 0;

   $result = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order.list');
      echo ($result[1]["order_id"]);

      //var_dump($result);


   foreach ($lines as $line)

   {

      set_time_limit(60);



      $fields = explode("\t", $line);

      $ShippedOrderId = $fields[0];
        echo $ShippedOrderId . "<br/>";
      if (strlen($ShippedOrderId) == 4) { $ShippedOrderId = '10000' . $ShippedOrderId; }



      if (is_numeric($ShippedOrderId))

      {

         // Check if customer exists

         $customer_exists = null;

         try

         {

            $customer_exists = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order.info', $ShippedOrderId);
         }

         catch (exception $e)

         {

            echo 'Exception: ' . $e . "<br/>";

         }

         if (($customer_exists != null) && ($customer_exists != ''))

         { 

            echo 'In with ' . $ShippedOrderId . "<br/>";

            $order_info = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order.info', $ShippedOrderId);

             ?><pre><?php print_r($order_info); ?></pre><?php 



            // Skip order if already completed or shipped

            if (($order_info['status'] != 'processing') && ($order_info['status'] != 'pending'))

            {

               $dupecount++;

               continue;

            }



            $comment = '<b><br>*** Order has shipped. ***</b><br/><br/>' . 

                       '<b>3PL order number:</b> ' .  $fields[1] . '<br/>' . 

                       '<b>Weight:</b> ' .  $fields[2] . '<br/>' . 

                       '<b>Shipped via:</b> ' .  $fields[3] . '<br/>' . 

                       '<b>Tracking number:</b> ' .  $fields[4] . '<br/>' . 

                       '<b>Ship date:</b> ' .  $fields[5] . '<br/>' . 

                       '<b>Postage:</b> ' .  $fields[6] . '<br/>' . 

                       '<b>Fulfillment:</b> ' .  $fields[7] . '<br/>' . 

                       '<b>Per packslip:</b> ' .  $fields[8];



            // Make shipment and add tracking number

            if ($fields[3] == 'UPS-RESIDENTIAL') { $shippedby = 'ups'; $shipname = 'UPS Ground'; }

            elseif ($fields[3] == 'UPS-2') { $shippedby = 'ups'; $shipname = 'UPS 2nd Day Air'; }

            elseif ($fields[3] == 'UPS-OVERNIGHT') { $shippedby = 'ups'; $shipname = 'UPS Next Day Air Saver'; }

            elseif ($fields[3] == 'USPS-PRI') { $shippedby = 'usps'; $shipname = 'USPS Priority'; }

            elseif ($fields[3] == 'CANADA') { $shippedby = 'custom'; $shipname = 'MSI Canada (Standard) '; }

            elseif ($fields[3] == 'MSITRACK') { $shippedby = 'custom'; $shipname = 'MSI Canada (Express)'; }

            else { $shippedby = 'custom'; }

            // Attempt to create the order, notify on failure

            try { $newShipmentId = $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order_shipment.create', array($ShippedOrderId, array(), $comment, true, false, $shippedby, $shipname, $fields[4])); }

            catch (Exception $e) { echo 'Shipment creation failed on order '. $ShippedOrderId . ': ', $e->getMessage(); }

            // Add comment to order with all the info

            $client->call($sess_id, 'sales_order.addComment', array($ShippedOrderId, 'complete',  $comment,  false));



            $mail_content .= $line . "\n";

            $importcount++;

         }

      }

   }



   $mail_content .= "\n===\n\n";



   $mail_content .= $dupecount . " shipments already in cart.\n\n" . $importcount . " new shipments imported on " . date('m/d/Y') . " at " . date('g:ia', strtotime('+1 hour')) . " EST.\n\n";



   // Close API session

   $client->endSession($sess_id);



   mail($mail_to, 'Magento Shipping Import for ' . date('m/d/Y'), $mail_content);

   mail($mail_to2, 'Magento Shipping Import for ' . date('m/d/Y'), $mail_content);

   mail($mail_to3, 'Magento Shipping Import for ' . date('m/d/Y'), $mail_content);

   mail($mail_to4, 'Magento Shipping Import for ' . date('m/d/Y'), $mail_content);

   //mail($mail_to5, 'Magento Shipping Import for ' . date('m/d/Y'), $mail_content);



?>

<pre><?php echo $mail_content; ?></pre>
```

When I echo $shippedOrderId within the loop I get this (sample):

"The order numbers are: string(9) "100015822" 
Exception: SoapFault exception: [100] Requested order not exists. in /home/ab71714/public_html/exporter/importer-sftp.php:140 Stack trace: #0 /home/ab71714/public_html/exporter/importer-sftp.php(140): SoapClient->__call('call', Array) #1 /home/ab71714/public_html/exporter/importer-sftp.php(140): SoapClient->call('0f128ddbbbfc007...', 'sales_order.inf...', '100015822') #2 {main}
The order numbers are: string(9) "100015842" 
Exception: SoapFault exception: [100] Requested order not exists. in /home/ab71714/public_html/exporter/importer-sftp.php:140 Stack trace: #0 /home/ab71714/public_html/exporter/importer-sftp.php(140): SoapClient->__call('call', Array) #1 /home/ab71714/public_html/exporter/importer-sftp.php(140): SoapClient->call('0f128ddbbbfc007...', 'sales_order.inf...', '100015842') #2 {main}
The order numbers are: string(9) "100015878" "

Comment: Can you echo out $ShippedOrderId to see if it is stored in the Session.   When I upgraded a client to 1.7 recently, I had issues getting the sessions all straightened out.   **EDIT** THe reason I mention this is your exception is telling you said order is non existent.  Have you checked the database as well to make sure the order is "really" there?

Comment: good call.  first thing is make sure all your params check out; $sess_id, and $ShippedOrderId, and for the table param, make sure the shippedOrderId is in the table.

Comment: @Zak do you know what table and column I need to be looking in? I added what $shippedorderid echos above.

Comment: is that order id in the table?  is there a table called sales_order with a column info?

Comment: It's in a few tables ...  `sales_flat_order`  ...  `sales_flat_order_grid`  ...  `sales_flat_quote`  ...  `sales_flat_shipment_grid`  ...  depending on your install  .. the term 'flat' may not be in the table name

Comment: hmm good I'll look into that. Just curious- do you know if these are the only tables that represent the total sales as well? I have a similar issue I'm concurrently dealing with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14349842/how-to-approach-dilemma-export-orders-from-old-magento-system-import-into-new-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what your calling (/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php) :

```
public function info($orderIncrementId)
```

Make sure you're using the increment id when setting $shippedOrderId:

```
$ShippedOrderId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

It seems that you are connecting successfully, you have an error from the API that the order doesn't exist. Not really sure what else it would be causing the problem. Try debugging the session_id and client params if that doesn't work.